# PHP Create Download Link

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $file = SEVENCE_DATA_ROOT."/resource/devdemo/promo_card.tiff";
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-type: application/tiff');
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");// some browsers need this
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=promo_card.tiff");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

My issue is that the download image can't be viewed. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: And how in the world is this related to regex >_<

Comment: Would you like to offer the return value of `readfile($file);` ?

Comment: For image response Content-Type should be image/jpeg

Comment: I recommend you check the file exists: http://dk1.php.net/file_exists

Comment: Is the image file not opening on the destination or it is not downloading at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
Content-Type: application/force-download");// some browsers need this
```

No browser does need this. It's a dirty glitch..

Reasons why your file cannot be opened:

1. You have a space or invisible characters at the beginning of your script
2. the path you are loading the file from might be wrong and it doesn't even read from it (what size is the downloaded file?)
3. the file simply is corrupt
4. you don't have a `tiff`-viewer

The correct mime type is `image/tiff` (instead of `application/tiff`)